# Longest increasing subsequence linear time

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was reading the longest increasing subsequence problem:
Given array A={a_1,a_2,...,a_n}, find the length of the longest increasing subsequence (not necessarily contiguous)
I thought of a recursive solution, which with memoization (or DP) has complexity = O( n * max(a_i) ).
so basically n * range of a_i's.
All the solutions I found are O(n^2) or O(nlogn), is there something wrong logically with this solution?

Here is the code:
Without loss of generality , assume all a_i's > 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int count = 0;
int lis(int A[], int loc, int length, int ** table, int max_so_far=0){
count++;
    if (loc == length)
  return 0;

    if (table[loc][max_so_far] != -1)
      return table[loc][max_so_far];

int val1 = 0, val2 = 0;
val1 = lis(A, loc+1, length, table, max_so_far);
if (max_so_far < A[loc])
    val2 = 1 + lis(A, loc+1, length, table, A[loc]);
    table[loc][max_so_far] = max(val1,val2);
return max(val1,val2); 
}

int main(){
int A[]={10, 11, 12, 9, 8, 7, 5, 6};
     int A[]={1,3,2,5,1,3,2,5,1,3,2,5,1,3,2,5,1,3,2,5,1,3,2,5,1,3,2,5, 1,3,2,5, 1,3,2,5, 1,3,2,5, 1,3,2,5, 1,3,2,5};
    int ** table;
int n = 49;
    int range = 6;
table = new int*[n];
    for (int i =0;i<n;i++){
      table[i] = new int[range];
      for(int j=0;j<range;j++)
       table[i][j] = -1;
}
    count = 0;
    cout<<lis(A, 0, n, table, 0)<<endl;
cout<<"Number of calls made: "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a convoluted and space inefficient way to write the standard O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the point is not the code, the point is the running time of this problem, which I believe is not O(n^2) in this implementation.

Comment: The running time is O(n^2) in the worst case and on average.

Comment: Thanks for the statement but the table initialization is n*max{a_i} , obviously not n^2. And the value of lis() is computed at most n*max{a_i} times since the values are saved there. Please explain why you think it is O(n^2).

Comment: Because for each element, you set it at some point as max_so_far and check every following element for possible extension of the sequence.

Comment: Just trace how your algorithm work on the numbers {1, 2, 3, ..., n}

Comment: Added a counter for you to see how many times the function is called. n is 49 : 49*49 = 2401. The number of calls made is 355, which is definitely not O(n^2) and more like O(n*max). The reason is that the range of numbers is less than n since the integers are not restricted to be distinct...

Comment: Did you run it for {1, 2, ..., n}? No. That you have found some specific case with less number of operations tells us nothing about worst case or average case of operations. Range of numbers is irrelevant - it will perform exactly the same operations if you, say, multiply each number by 1 billion.

Comment: Anyway, stop arguing and move along. Write a paper if you're so sure.

Comment: If it is {1,2,...,n} the max a_i is n, and in this case it will be n^2. Range is relevant since the memoization table is range dependent and needs to be initialized, and if you can't see that you should stop arguing and think for a minute and run the example. It's not an argument anyway if you don't have anything to add please stop replying and let other people help

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with you approach. The complexity is, as you say, O(n*|A|) where |A| is the number of unique elements. In the worst case, |A|=n.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I believe without the table initializatin, it is indeed O(n*|A|) or if we used a table[int][hashmap<int,int>>] instead of table[int][int] we would make the average running time O(n*|A|) I believe. But yes the point is that given my table implementation it should be O(n*max{a_i}). 
However I tried to google this problem everywhere, and only found O(n^2) or O(nlogn) solutions. This is the wikipedia page too : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence . This is the main reason why I thought I might have something wrong.